How can I measure slot contention severity in BigQuery?
We have a high volume of BQ queries running in many GCP projects using slots across 8 reservations.  I want a metric to understand how impactful slot contention is/how much it's slowing down queries and how that has changed over recent weeks and months. A couple ideas I've had, mostly using data found in the jobs_by_organization information schema view:

using the slot_contention boolean query_info.performance_insights.stage_performance_standalone_insights to measure how many jobs had at least one stage where slot_contention=true, or to compare to total stage count to see what % of all stages had slot_contention=true

using one of the waitms fields in job_stages to look at average wait time across jobs or stages, although the docs say that wait time is not always due to slot contention

looking at duration/total_slot_ms , although slot contention is not the only reason for a query to be slow so i'm hesitant to go that route.


What is the best way to measure contention? Hoping for thoughts on the above and any other ideas.
